# PHP is ignoring code like var_dump(), die(), etc

Tags: php

This is a very weird situation like I've never seen in my life.
For some reason PHP is ignoring a lot of code inside a static function.

Here is the example:

```
static function describe($tableName, $columns = '*') {
    var_dump($tableName);
    die();
    $md5 = ...code...
    if (!empty($content = Cache::get($md5))) {
        return unserialize($content);
    }
```

I keep getting the error

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '=', expecting ')'
```

in

```
if (!empty($content = Cache::get($md5))) {
```

And yes it recognises the class `Cache` and its function.

Can anyone guide me?

Comment: What does the `::get` function return?

Comment: why do you define `$columns` in the function and not above the function?

Comment: To complain that PHP was “ignoring” stuff while you still have parse errors, now that is a special kind of […]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Prior to PHP 5.5, `empty()` function can only support strings.

Any other input provided to it like: a function call e.g.

```
if (empty(myfunction()) {
 // ...
}
```

would result parse error.

[As per documentation:](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php)

> Note: Prior to PHP 5.5, empty() only supports variables; anything else
>   will result in a parse error. In other words, the following will not
>   work: empty(trim($name)). Instead, use trim($name) == false.

Better way, get your `$content` variable first and then check if it is not empty.

Rather than initialising it and checking its emptiness simultaneously.

You can separate the `if` statement in two parts like this:

```
if ($content = Cache::get($md5) && !empty($content)) {
 return unserialize($content);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this,

```
if (!empty($content) && $content = Cache::get($md5)) {
        return unserialize($content);
}
```

OR : To get easy readability

```
if (!empty($content){
   if($content = Cache::get($md5)){
       return unserialize($content);
   }
}
```